# Find mailfolder in Outlook with Redemption

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook-redemption

I try to find a folder in an Outlook account (I use Multiple accounts) using VBA and Redemption by using the FIND method but I cannot get it to work. On the Redemption webpage there is a reference made to an example and this may help but unfortunately the example isn't there.

Here's my code so far:

```
Public Function FindFolderRDO(strCrit As String) As String

    If Not TempVars![appdebug] Then On Error GoTo Err_Proc
    
    Dim objRdoSession As Redemption.RDOSession
    Dim objRdoFolder As RDOFolder
    Dim strFoundFolder As String
    Dim objFoundFolder As RDOFolder
    Dim strFolderName As String

    Set objRdoSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
    objRdoSession.Logon
    objRdoSession.MAPIOBJECT = Outlook.Session.MAPIOBJECT
    
    strFolderName = "\\[mailbox name]\[foldername]\[foldername]" 'actual names removed
    
    Set objRdoFolder = objRdoSession.GetFolderFromPath(strFolderName)
    Debug.Print objRdoFolder.Parent.Name 'Prints the folder name

    Set objFoundFolder = objRdoFolder.Folders.Find("LIKE 'strCrit%' ") 'Does not work
    Debug.Print objFoundFolder.Name

    strFoundFOlder = objRdoFolder.Folders.Find("LIKE 'strCrit%' ") 'Does not work
    Debug.Print strFoundFOlder

Exit_Proc:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objRdoFolder = Nothing
    Set objRdoSession = Nothing
    Set objFoundFolder = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_Proc:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error: " & CStr(Err.Number) & vbCrLf & _
                   "Desc: " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                   "Source: " & Err.Source & vbCrLf & _
                   "Library: " & Application.CurrentProject.Name & vbCrLf & _
                   "Module: Mod_RDO" & vbCrLf & _
                   "Function: FindFolderRDO" & vbCrLf, _
                   vbCritical, "Error"
    End Select
    Resume Exit_Proc
End Function
```

Purpose of this function is to find a subfolder (can be up to 4 dimensions deep) having an unique case number of 6 numbers (for example "200332") on the first 6 positions. This function should provide NULL if not found or the full path and the name of the found folder.
I can create the full path with a seperate function (calling the parent folder until top level) but maybe there is a procedure in Redemption such as "fullpath" which I overlooked.
Eventually I want to use this function to delete, move or rename the mailbox folder.

My main question is how to use the "Find(Filter)" method. But any reply on the full path is welcome as well.

Thx! Art.

Answer (score 0):

You are you trying to find a suborder with a name that starts with `"strCrit"`?

You are almost there:

```
Set objFoundFolder = objRdoFolder.Folders.Find("Name LIKE 'strCrit%' ")
```

Comment: Actually no, strCrit is the variable name. So it should be 

Set objFoundFolder = objRdoFolder.Folders.Find("Name LIKE '" & strCrit & "%' ")

But this still shows a run-time error 438 – Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: What version of Redemption are you using? RDOFolders.Find / FindNext / Restrict / Sort methods were added in version 5.21.

Comment: AH, that's the reason. Apparently I'm still on 5.17.